# GET Request with body/multipart form data in Java

Tags: java, http, get, request

Is there any way to send such request, even with external libraries?

Comment: Most libraries will allow you to set a body, but the web server is not obligated to read it. Do something else, use POST.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. GET doesn't have a body. GET means you are trying to fetch a resource. So GET doesn't need any Content-Type header.

Multipart body is sent to upload something. That means it is used to create/update resource.
So only POST & PUT works with multipart body. If someone is trying to use multipart with GET, it is conceptually wrong.

Comment: I now that its not a good practice at all. But other team justify this by amount and  length of input that we are using to search and it my not be safe to use url parameters

Comment: Then you can go ahead with POST instead of GET. I don't think your team would have any issue calling a POST url instead of a GET url. And you can justify that. Basically POST is used to create resource. You are creating a results object & that is a temporary resource that you are not storing on the server. And you are just fetching it in the same call as response.